# Parse App Crashing On Some Devices

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I have an iPhone app which is using parse as backend. I have successfully integrated everything.I've test it and it's running perfectly on my devices ( simulator and physical devices ).
The problem is that my clients are complaining that the app is crashing on their devices when trying to fetch data from Parse.

What can be the problem?

Comment: have you asked your client, On which ios version they are testing?

Comment: Testing it on iOS 8.4

Comment: i also have made ios app with parse backend and this is working fine in ios 7.1 and 8.4 also

Comment: Did you give different versions of the app to someone to test?

Comment: I was wondering that I may have to turn off "Require Revocable Sessions"

Comment: Nope, not right now. Have you checked your parse api calls? is it crossed limits...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85098/discussion-between-vakas-and-chetan-prajapati).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this with the following.

1. I've cleared all the Session logs.
2. I've set "Require Revocable Sessions" to "No" in settings.
   [image]

And now both the apps are working fine on my clients phones.

Answer (score 1):

There is high chance that this happen due to network issues, for example if the device is on airplane mode. When device is in offline mode it will try couple of time and throws;

```
0xa3884: b 0xa3860; _40-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]block_invoke_2 + 340 at PFTask.m:329
```

And console will state;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'....
```

This may or may not be the reason in your case, but there's a possibility.

Also, may I suggest the user of [Fabric.io](https://fabric.io) for your app release to your clients. So you can get a clear understating about when, how and why the app crashes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well they are testing it with their data turned on, not in airplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest definitely adding an analytic api to monitor crashes etc...

try this: http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk/

Also you should implement a network check when deploying apps that communicate with a backend so you are in control of whatever network scenario arrises.

try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Also did you try deleting the app off of your device and downloading the way your clients are?

Also a crash isnt specific. Is it just hanging, does it kill the app etc...? If you know a client have them check the device logs and send you over a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Parse may not be the problem.
Have you try to "Reset content and settings" on simulator and launch again app? Does still it work?

Another possibility is that you manage in a wrong way errors from parse request.

Example:

```
func postNewPerson(person: Person?, completion: (success: Bool, result: Person?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var p = PFObject(className: "Person")
    p["name"] = person.name
    p["lastName"] = person.lastName
    p.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            completion(success: true, result: person, error: nil)
        } else {
            completion(success: nil, result: nil, error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

when you call this function you have to test for success/error:

```
service.postNewPerson(person: person) { (success, result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil && success == true {
        /* Your request is ok */
    } else {
        /* Something wrong */
    }
 }
```

Comment: 1. I never had any issues on my simulator or devices. My remote clients are complaining about this. And it's happening in two different apps.

Comment: could be something about api key/access permission?

Comment: No, because if I'm giving my app to my client through test-flight, how can api key be the problem.